# Ask for the ID (Identity) that created their own to add a new record in an SQL table. Silverlight

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, silverlight

I need help, I have a SQL table (Order) has a field ID int Identity, and another table (OrderDetail) where one of his fields is this ID

The Order table struct is:

```
ID (PK, int, Identity, Not Null)
Service (char(10), Not Null)
TypeReposition (char(10), Null)
```

And the OrderDetail table struct is:

```
IDOrder (PK, FK, int, Not Null)  <- this must be equal to corresponding ID in Order
Status (PK, char(25), Not Null)
StatusDate (PK, datetime, Not Null)
```

to insert a new record in the Order table, I make this:

```
Order newOrder = new Order();
newOrder.Service = ((TypeService)cbTypeService.SelectedItem).Service;
newOrder.TypeReposition = null;

OrderDomainDataSource.DataView.Add(newOrder);

OrderDomainDataSource.DomainContext.SubmitChanges(so =>
{
    if (so.HasError)
    {
        //Handle errors from submit
        so.MarkErrorAsHandled();
    }
    if (OrderDomainDataSource.CanLoad)
        OrderDomainDataSource.Load();
}, null);
```

The ID is generated automatically when the insert is done.
Immediately after this, I need insert the corresponding OrderDetail record, but for that I need to know the ID generated for the Order record, how I know this??

I'm using Silverlight 5 with WCF Ria Services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution:

```
newOrderDetail.IDOrder = ((Order)OrderDomainDataSource.DataView.CurrentItem).ID;
```

Because OrderDomainDataSource.DataView.CurrentItem, after SubmitChanges, points to the Order record that I added previously